# Find out the number of search query made to my Solr

Tags: solr

I have 3 solr instances with zookeeper
Is there a way in Solr to find out the number of search query made to my solr instances? like per day/week/month wise?

Comment: Have you seen https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/performance-statistics-reference.html or https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/monitoring-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html ?

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for pointing me the API. Trying to get the select query between the date range. E.g.: per month.

Comment: That won't be anything Solr provides as far as I know; that would be the task of whatever log aggregation / time series database/service you use.

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't allow you to have statistics grouped by day/month/year.
Despite this, you can integrate your Solr cloud with third-party services like Prometheus and Grafana to store, monitor, and alert historical metrics.

Check this out: https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_3/monitoring-solr-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html

1. Be sure the metrics are enabled on the `solr.xml` config file
2. Install and configure your `prometheus-exporter`
3. Install and configure Prometheus and Grafana
4. Create the query you need on Grafana: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/#query-options